# execute external command / application from java

Tags: java, process, execution

I'm looking for a package to support reliably executing external processes from Java. My criteria:

- Abstract over OS. So if I want to run 'foo', it will look for 'foo.bat', 'foo.exe' under windows and 'foo' under other OSs (or, have a way of passing a map of os->command)
- Being able to execute Java classes by simply giving the class name and arguments (so the package locates the java command, copies jvm flags and then executes)
- Process stdout and stderr properly
- Watchdog / Monitoring capabilities

I've looked at commons-exec but it looks like it answers only 3 & 4. Ant has support for execution but looks like an overkill to use it for this purpose only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will likely have to go with 'commons-exec' and then roll up your sleeves and write some code.

Those are pretty specific requirements.

Comment: Does this mean you've encountered this issue and did some research to find there's nothing available, or just by looking at the question it looks too specific to you?

Comment: I've worked on projects dealing with the last two points (3 & 4), and I've used commons-exec and Ant. But I have never seen a requirement similar to your first two points.